# Android DB: delete() API not returning number of rows deleted

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-delete

I have the following function:

```
public int deleteRow(String id){
    SQLiteDatabase db = Util.getDatabase();
    int rows = 0;

        rows = dB.delete("TABLE_NAME", "ID=?", new String[] {id});

    return rows;
}
```

Now i am passing a valid id which exits in the table. The row is deleted but `rows` is still returned as 0.

Could someone please help?
Thanks

Comment: i assume `dB` is an `SQLiteDatabase` object?

Comment: @pskink: yes it is SQLiteDatabase

Comment: did you try to dump TABLE_NAME contents before and after calling `deleteRow` ?

Comment: @pskink: I did not do that but: Before calling delete i queried the id and this row was returned.  After calling delete, I query the row based on ID and the query returns nothing confirming that it was deleted. But then why were number of rows returned as 0.

Comment: just call `Cursor c = dB.rawQuery()` and `Log.d` "c.getCount()" that's all